# Arduino c++ classes, How to make instance variables of another class/library

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, arduino

I'm working with an Arduino UNO in my first attempt to use the OO in Wiring.
I just have a question which I need help with;
I'm using a class for a DHT22 sensor from freetronics, found here http://www.freetronics.com/products/humidity-and-temperature-sensor-module.
Say I have a class i made called Sensor, where DHT is the library for the freetronics sensor, and DHT dht(5, DHT22) Initialises the sensor on pin 5 (which could be any digital pin):

```
#include "arduino.h"
#include <DHT.h>

DHT dht(1, DHT22);

class Sensor{
  public:
    Sensor(int);

};

Sensor::Sensor(int pin){
  DHT dht(pin, DHT22);
}
```

This is the only way to initialise DHT that does not throw compile errors, even though it is re-initialising that variiable, but if I try to put `DHT dht()` as a private variable it doesn't work.

But my question is, if i create two of these Objects, will they be using the same object reference `dht`? Or is the initialising code for `dht` in the correct area to act only inside the instances' scope?

Please tell me if this is confusing, and I appreciate any help in advance, Thank You :)

Comment: `DHT dht()` is not declaring an instance variable. It is declaring a function. You need `DHT dht;`, without the parentheses. If its constructor requires parameters, then you should use the initialization syntax in the constructor: `Sensor (int pin) : dht(pin) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: This was perfect, it worked. Thanks so much!
Is that Initialisation syntax required or can I do it in the function ? Is there a difference. Either way thank you so much!

Comment: yes, it's required. No, you can't do it inside the function (why do you want another way when there's one that is perfectly fit for the purpose?), yes, there is a difference (assignment is not initialization, think references, `const`-qualified objects, ...). Please read an introductory C++ book.