# how to make instance variables of another class library in arduino

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, arduino

I am starting with the creation of arduino libraries. I have errors when including libraries that are already created.

This is to include the DHT22 sensor library in another library using the Arduino Ide.

References:

[Arduino c++ classes, How to make instance variables of another class/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602268/arduino-c-classes-how-to-make-instance-variables-of-another-class-library)

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial

Library DHT22:

https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library

Used files:

This file temperaturaPOO.h

```
#ifndef temperaturaPOO_h
#define temperaturaPOO_h
#include "Arduino.h" 
#include <DHT.h>

DHT dht(1, DHT22);

class temperaturaPOO {  
    int sensor_humedad;
    int sensor_temperatura;
    public:
        temperaturaPOO(int); // ?? x
        void mostrar();     
};
#endif
```

This file temperaturaPOO.cpp

```
#include <temperaturaPOO.h>
temperaturaPOO::temperaturaPOO(int pin){
    DHT dht(pin, DHT22);
}

void temperaturaPOO::mostrar()
{
    sensor_humedad = dht.readHumidity();  
    sensor_temperatura = dht.readTemperature();

    Serial.print("Humidity:");
    Serial.println(sensor_humedad);
    Serial.print("Temperature:");
    Serial.println(sensor_temperatura);
}
```

This file blinkLedPOO.ino

```
#include <temperaturaPOO.h>
temperaturaPOO temp(1); // se instancia
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
    temp.mostrar();
}
```

Comment: where is temperaturaPOO.h? Is it in library folder or in the same folder with .ino file?

Comment: is in the library folder.

Comment: This is the procedure:
I create a folder with the name temperaturePOO. Within it there are two files and a folder, this folder also has the name of temperaturePOO and inside it is only the file temperaturaPOO.ino.Outside it are the files:

- temperaturaPOO.h
- temperaturePOO.cpp

What I do is zip the main folder and then import it as a normal arduino library.

Comment: Can you tell me why do you have `DHT dht(1, DHT22);` in .h file and what error do you get in console?

Comment: Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_455009\core\core_arduino_avr_nano_cpu_atmega328_0c812875ac70eb4a9b385d8fb077f54c.a
libraries\temperaturaPOO\temperaturaPOO.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `dht':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `dht'

sketch\temperaturaPOO.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compilando para la tarjeta Arduino Nano.

Comment: this is my base. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602268/arduino-c-classes-how-to-make-instance-variables-of-another-class-library

Comment: I will write the answer, try and tell me does it works, and please do not downvote, just tell me, OK?

Answer (score 0):

"You have the problem because you tried to define `DHT dht(1, DHT22);` multiple time.

Try this: 

 your .h file should look like

```
#ifndef temperaturaPOO_h
#define temperaturaPOO_h
#include "Arduino.h" 
#include <DHT.h>

class temperaturaPOO {  
private:
    DHT dht;            //define dth here
    int sensor_humedad;
    int sensor_temperatura;
    public:
        temperaturaPOO(int); // ?? x
        void mostrar();     
};
#endif
```

and .cpp

```
#include "temperaturaPOO.h"
temperaturaPOO::temperaturaPOO(int pin){
    dth = DHT(pin, DHT22);
}

void temperaturaPOO::mostrar()
{
    sensor_humedad = dht.readHumidity();  
    sensor_temperatura = dht.readTemperature();

    Serial.print("Humidity:");
    Serial.println(sensor_humedad);
    Serial.print("Temperature:");
    Serial.println(sensor_temperatura);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [one of the links you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26602268/arduino-c-classes-how-to-make-instance-variables-of-another-class-library). The comments explain how to initialize objects in a constructor. When you pass a member constructor, you want to use [initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list).

The header should look something like this.

```cpp
#ifndef temperaturaPOO_h
#define temperaturaPOO_h
#include "Arduino.h" 
#include <DHT.h>

class temperaturaPOO {  
    int sensor_humedad;
    int sensor_temperatura;
public:
    temperaturaPOO(int);
    void mostrar();

private:
    DHT dht;
};
#endif
```

And here is the implementation. Look how `dht` is initialized.

```cpp
#include <temperaturaPOO.h>

temperaturaPOO::temperaturaPOO(int pin): dht(pin, DHT22) {}

void temperaturaPOO::mostrar()
{
    sensor_humedad = dht.readHumidity();  
    sensor_temperatura = dht.readTemperature();

    Serial.print("Humidity:");
    Serial.println(sensor_humedad);
    Serial.print("Temperature:");
    Serial.println(sensor_temperatura);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works!!

I did not read the sensor data, so I added these two lines at the beginning of the method and it works properly.

temperaturaPOO.cpp

```
void temperaturaPOO::mostrar()
{
    dht.begin(); // add this
    delay(2000); // add this
    sensor_humedad = dht.readHumidity();  
    sensor_temperatura = dht.readTemperature();
    Serial.print("Humidity:");
    Serial.println(sensor_humedad);
    Serial.print("Temperature:");
    Serial.println(sensor_temperatura);
}
```

I have one doubt in the initialization of the attributes of the constructor:

How do you read this line, in other words how to be documented to make a good understanding, thank you!

This Line:

```
temperaturaPOO::temperaturaPOO(int pin): dht(pin, DHT22) {}
```